# obtain value from another table then filter on average

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created two tables: `Department(deptno,dname,location)` and  `Employee(empno,ename,post,gender,salary,deptno)`. I linked foreign key to `deptno` to link the tables.

My question is how can I find the name of department whose average salary is greater than 20000.

If it were inside Employee table I would have it, but how can I get it from the Department table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have not heard of joins and aggregate before, well check this to show location, department name and avg salary of the department whose avg salary > 20000

```
select d.location, d.dname, avg(e.salary)
  from department d, employee e
 where d.deptno = e.deptno
 group by d.location, d.dname
having avg(e.salary) > 20000
```

Comment: it worked man thanks alot.. can u plz explain me  select d.dname,avg(e.salary) from department d,employee e where d.deptno=e.deptno group by d.dname having avg(e.salary)>20000   ....here what did d and e actuall did

Comment: d and e are alias to both the tables, its easy to refer variables instead of using complete table name

Comment: was i to use table name how would the code be then...i cannot get this...show it using a table name just once thank you

Comment: If you remove alias, then table name would be required only in the ambiguous field deptno, including join statement (where clause)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    d.dname
FROM    
    Department AS d
    JOIN Employee AS e ON d.deptno = e.deptno
GROUP BY
    d.dname
HAVING AVG(e.salary) > 20000
```

Comment: I wish we wouldn't encourage this type of questions where they don't show the slightest effort.

Comment: maybe add some sample data in your question and the query you have tried and the results you're getting.  Then explain why the data doesn't match what you're expecting.  Or any errors you may be getting